# What limits L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: limits

I have very often heard that L'Hospital's rule can only be applied when we have $0 \over 0$ or  $\infty \over \infty$ form in limit.

But what I do no know is what prevents us from applying it in case of other forms of limits like of type $1^\infty$.

I reckon it has something to do with how L'Hospital's rule is derived but I am not sure.

Question : what actually prevents the usage of L'Hospital's rule to all cases of limits?

Comment: Why on earth would it work? What you should ask yourself first is **why** it **does** work in some cases. Then it should hopefully become obvious why it doesn't work in other cases.

Comment: That is what exactly what I wanted to know and so I asked this question.

Comment: You may perhaps know that there are theorems which involve hypotheses and thus their conclusion holds only under those hypotheses. A proper statement of the L'Hospital's Rule mentions the hypotheses under which it holds. One should not use any result without knowing its actual statement / formulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't apply L'Hospital's Rule directly in that situation because it doesn't work.

For instance, If $f(x)=1+\frac1x$ and $g(x)=x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=e$. However,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)^{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac1{x^2}=0\neq e.$$

Comment: Yes, but **why** does it not work in $some$ cases?

Comment: Did you ever read the proof of L'Hopital's Rule? It is *essential* for it that you are dealing with quotients.

Comment: Sorry, Not to sound like a broken record but why quotients? If you could give me link where I could read the proof(or give it yourself) it should help. Thanks

Comment: There are several ones [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505535/proof-of-lhospitals-rule/505788), for instance.

Comment: Oh thanks! I get now why we need quotients thanks.

Comment: Accepted as this answer led me to proofs which ultimately cleared my doubt. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

For example of limit of the form $\;1^\infty\;$, take the classic

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}$$

So, by continuity of the exponential function, you need to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}$$

and the last one is just a $\;\frac00\;$ form limit which you can solve easily with L'Hospital...!

The above example is classic and something similar can be applied to most $\;1^\infty\;$ limits used in Calculus I courses

Comment: What I wanna know is why you cant apply it directly to another form and need to convert it.

Comment: Because the other form is neither $\;\frac\infty\infty\;$ nor $\;\frac00\;$ . Simple.

Comment: Sorry I think I should have asked better. What I want to know is why L'Hôpital's rule fails in cases like 1/$\infty$

Comment: Do you know the proofs (at least the simplest one) of the L-H theorem? Then you can see that the case $\;\frac1\infty\;$ doesn't work. It's like asking "why only a straight triangle fulfills Pythagoras theorem? Well, because !

Comment: I get it now thanks! I have seem some proofs and it has completely clear thanks for your answer