# Can the following proof of L'Hospital's rule be made rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**L'Hospital's rule:** let $f$, and $g$ be real functions differentiable on $(a,b)$ except possibly at a point $x_0\in (a,b)$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=0$, if $g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ (except possibly at $x_0$), and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists, then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

---

The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505535/proof-of-lhospitals-rule/505788) (second answer in the link) uses linear approximations. Letting
$$\eta (h)= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)$$
we have that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\eta(h)=0$, and one can write $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)+\eta(h)$. Defining $\zeta(h)$ similarly for $g$, we have
$$\frac{f(x+h)}{g(x+h)}=\frac{f(x)+f'(x)+\eta(h)}{g(x)+g'(x)+\zeta(h)}$$

Taking the limit as $x\rightarrow x_0$ gives
$$\frac{f(x_0+h)}{g(x_0+h)}=\frac{hf'(x_0)+\eta(h)}{hg'(x_0)+\zeta(h)}$$

and the result follows by taking the limit as $h\rightarrow 0$.

---

There are two obvious problems with the proof.

- First of all $\eta$ and $\zeta$ are functions of two variables ($x$ and $h$), maybe this could be resolved by letting $\eta(h)=\frac{f(x_0+h)}{h}-f'(x_0)$, but this lead us to the second problem:
- How do we know any of the quotients are well-defined? It might be the case that $g(x_0+h)=0$, for example.

Can these two issues be resolved as to make the proof rigorous?

Comment: The proof is already pretty rigorous. We consider $\eta,\zeta$ for fixed $x$, so there's no issue here. Your idea to resolve the "issue" is what's done anyway, essentially. Wether we use $x_0$ and $x$ or $x$ and $x+h$ doesn't matter in the slightest. It's just a change of variables. And the other issue is resolved by the fact that it is assumed as a premise that there is a neighborhood of $x$ in which the quotient is defined.

Comment: Which premise assumes that there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ for which the quotient $f(x_0+h)/g(x_0+h)$ is defined?

Comment: One you haven't listed, but which is required to even make sense of the claim. The quotient needs to be defined in order to take its limit.

Comment: Wait, how would one deal with the fact that $f(x_0)$ need not equal $0$ and $f'(x_0)$ not being defined?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the values of $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$ are. Only the limits as $x\to x_0$ matter.